# Twilio masked numbers with MMS messages

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to mask numbers between employees and customers, and I have so far gotten both SMS and voice to work, but I am having trouble figuring out how to pass on MMS messages.  Do I need to use the REST API, or should a response to the webhook be enough?  It's not like the REST API is that difficult.  It would just seem there should be a TwiML response that will work, like there is with SMS and voice.

In Python, I am using code similar to this:

```
import requests
from django.views import View
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse, Media
from django.http import HttpResponse


class SMSWebhook(View):
    def post(self, request):
        twilio_out = MessagingResponse()
        twil_in = request.POST
        # Call database to determine recipient's number
        scheduler_data = requests.post('my_server_url', data={'to': twil_in['To'], 'caller': twil_in['From']})
        scheduler_in = scheduler_data.json()[0]
        # check if it is a valid message
        if scheduler_data.status_code == 200:
            twilio_out.message(body=twil_in['Body'], to=scheduler_in['recipient'], from_=twil_in['To'])
            if twil_in['NumMedia']:
                for i in range(int(twil_in['NumMedia'])):
                    twilio_out.append(Media(twil_in['MediaUrl' + str(i)]))
        else:
            twilio_out.message('sms_default_message')
        return HttpResponse(str(twilio_out), content_type='text/xml')
```

The TwiML it produces is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
     <Message from="+XXXXXXXXXXX" to="+XXXXXXXXXXX" />
     <Media>https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/...</Media>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When sending MMS using TwiML you need to use the [`<Body>` and `<Media>` nouns](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message#nouns) inside of the [`<Message>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message). It looks like your `<Media>` is sitting outside of the `<Message>` in your example.

You probably want something like this instead:

```
    if scheduler_data.status_code == 200:
        message = twilio_out.message(to=scheduler_in['recipient'], from_=twil_in['To'])
        message.append(Body(twil_in['Body']))
        if twil_in['NumMedia']:
            for i in range(int(twil_in['NumMedia'])):
                message.append(Media(twil_in['MediaUrl' + str(i)]))
    else:
```

Note how I save a reference to the `<Message>` and then append the `<Media>` directly to it.

Let me know if this helps at all.